# How to display a range input slider vertically

Tags: html, css

I would like to display an `<input type="range" />` slider control vertically.  I'm only concerned with browsers that support the range slider control.

I've found some comments and references that seem to indicate that setting the height greater than the width will cause the browser to change the orientation automatically, but in my testing, that only <strike>works in Opera</strike> used to work in Opera, but not anymore.  How can I orient an HTML5 range slider vertically?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

First, set height greater than width.  This helps to get the layout right between browsers.  Applying left and right padding will also help with layout and positioning.

For Chrome (and other chromium based browsers), use `appearance: slider-vertical`.

For Firefox, add an `orient="vertical"` attribute to the html. Pity that they did it this way.  Visual styles should be controlled via CSS, not HTML.

```css
input[type=range][orient=vertical] {
    appearance: slider-vertical;
    width: 8px;
    height: 175px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" orient="vertical" />
```

---

My answer used to have a disclaimer here using about non-standardized behavior and the volatility of the web, but this answer is over 10 years old and the same CSS from 10 years ago still works today.  In fact [MDN includes this same advice in its documentation for `<input type="range">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#creating_vertical_range_controls).  Feel free to check the edit history of this answer to read up about that, but it is plain to me that this isn't going to change any time soon.

**Edit:** Famous last words!  [According to a comment in github](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/8413#issuecomment-1876018538), it looks like chromium will soon support changing the orientation via `writing-mode` in combination with `direction` to control whether sliding up increases or decreases the value.  And it seems [they're trying to get the standard updated to match](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4177#issuecomment-1876027817).  We'll see what happens!

Comment: +1 for the disclaimer about `-webkit-appearance` - I didn't know that. It changes everything.

Comment: Input element with type="range" in IE is very sensitive to width/height/display values. When using Bootstrap some of these values may be inadvertently overwritten (especially if you don't use blanket css as in the answer). For one of my vertical ranges I use css like this: .vert {
    -ms-writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; /* WebKit */
    height: 210px;
    width: 20px !important;
    padding: 0 5px;
    display: inline-block !important;
}

Comment: I'm definitely not a fan of `!important`.  It's always better to strengthen your selector.  Instead of just `.vert`, use something like `input[type=range].vert`.

Comment: This works, but the downside is that you can't use custom colors, shapes, ...etc for the range item. Think rotating will be the best for me.

Comment: well, I have a problem with using this solution, I browsed this page in Opera and it works fine, but when I use " <input type="range" orient="vertical" /> " in a practice webpage and open it in Opera it still appears horizontal, tried changing width and height, not working either , not even when used together. as of now I don't know how to use this, although I have been stuck in what is just a practice project, still it is pretty frustrating not to be able to get the code work.

Comment: @Hitman2847 - Are you including the CSS?  If you can provide a link (to jsfiddle, or something), I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: @gilly3 I did not, I will try it but in the meantime I archived and uploaded the files on MEGA.nz : https://mega.nz/file/P9sEyIzY#a2wZpRym0pxmXHvXJoSHkFwL3_k6aLfFN_gY032T9Jg

Comment: @Hitman2847 - The CSS in my answer is not optional.  If you didn't include the CSS, it won't work.

Comment: right thanks, I know JS, and HTML , but since I don't know CSS I couldn't use it, I will study CSS and then try this and get back here, thanks again

Comment: Progress report, Dec 2022: almost no progress.  You can use appearance: instead of -webkit-appearance: ... that's about it.
Firefox still requires orient=vertical, safari&chrome appearance: slider-vertical.  Each ignore the other.

Comment: PS: none of these work anymore: https://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html

Answer (score 94):

You can do this with css transforms, though be careful with container height/width. Also you may need to position it lower:

```css
input[type="range"] {
   position: absolute;
   top: 40%;
   transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="range"/>
```

---

or the 3d transform equivalent:

```
input[type="range"] {
   transform: rotateZ(270deg);
}
```

You can also use this to switch the direction of the slide by setting it to 180deg or 90deg for horizontal or vertical respectively.

Comment: Note you need to make it 270 if you want it to correspond with higher values you go up and lower values you go down. Edited your answer.

Comment: I prefer this approach as it supports custom css styling. With the other approach, custom styling makes the slider act funny

Comment: This is simple but brilliant

Comment: Instead of position: absolute you might use display: inline-block; with transform-origin.

Comment: @DenisGiffeler the position absolute isn't really part of this solution, it's just a convenient way to make the SO example display correctly. There are many ways to accomplish the positioning depending on your use case.

Answer (score 32):

Without changing the position to absolute, see below. This supports all recent browsers as well.

```css
.vranger {
  margin-top: 50px;
   transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg); /*do same for other browsers if required*/
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="vranger"/>
```

for very old browsers, you can use `-sand-transform: rotate(10deg);` from [CSS sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/)

or use

prefix selector such as `-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);` for IE9

Comment: also include something like   `transform-origin: center left;` to have slider be left-justified not center-justified.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.container {
    border: 3px solid #eee;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 20%
}

input[type=range].range {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    z-index: 200;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#e6e6e6), to(#d2d2d2));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #e6e6e6, #d2d2d2);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #e6e6e6, #d2d2d2);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #e6e6e6, #d2d2d2);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #e6e6e6, #d2d2d2)
}

input[type=range].range:focus {
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important
}

input[type=range].range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #555;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#4ddbff), to(#0cf));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #4ddbff, #0cf);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #4ddbff, #0cf);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #4ddbff, #0cf);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #4ddbff, #0cf)
}

input[type=range].round {
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px
}

input[type=range].round::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px
}

.vertical-lowest-first {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg)
}

.vertical-heighest-first {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-left: 0px">
    <br><br>
    <input class="range vertical-lowest-first" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
    <br><br><br>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <br><br>
    <input class="range vertical-heighest-first" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
    <br><br><br>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <br><br>
    <input class="range vertical-lowest-first round" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
    <br><br><br>
</div>


<div class="container" style="margin-right: 0px">
    <br><br>
    <input class="range vertical-heighest-first round" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
    <br><br><br>
</div>
```

Source: http://twiggle-web-design.com/tutorials/Custom-Vertical-Input-Range-CSS3.html

Comment: Source link includes demo showing various sliders with different style treatments.

Comment: Any explanation? What did the trick?

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple. I had implemented using `-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical`, It worked in chrome, Firefox, Edge

```
<input type="range">
```

```
input[type=range]{
    writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; /* WebKit */
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    outline: none;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: I still needed orient="vertical" on the input tag. Just a heads up!

Comment: @Tom Which browser?

Comment: @WΩLLE-ˈvɔlə It was a while ago, so I can't fully remember now, but I think it was Safari. I completely ignore IE these days if I can, so I think it must have been that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function(){
var slider = document.getElementById("sss");
 var  result = document.getElementById("final");
slider.oninput = function(){
    result.innerHTML = slider.value ;
}
}
```

```css
.slider{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
   
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.slider .container-slider{
    width: 600px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: rotate(90deg)
}

.slider .container-slider input[type="range"]{
    width: 60%;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0 20px
    
}

.slider .container-slider input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}



.slider .container-slider input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover{

box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(255,255,255,.3),
            0px 0px 15px rgba(255,255,255,.4),
            0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,.5),
            0px 0px 25px rgba(255,255,255,.6),
            0px 0px 30px rgba(255,255,255,.7)

}


.slider .container-slider .val {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #ACB6E5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: consolas;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1.3px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg)
}

.slider .container-slider .val::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #ACB6E5;
    top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="container-slider">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="" id="sss">
    <div class="val" id="final">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply,
Make wrapper for this input range with :

HTML:

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="range" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.input-wrapper{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    width:5px; /* fixed width */
}
```

and for input add:

```css
.input-wrapper > input{
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

with this simple css no extra browser support is required

Comment: You have a typo in your answer.  You need to use `class` as the attribute in the div, not `className`.  Trying out your CSS, the top of the slider gets clipped and isn't visible.  Maybe you can fix these things and update your answer?

Comment: thank you for pointing it out , it happned to be jsx code while it was supposed to be HTML5