# HTML does not work properly when used in WebIOPi

Tags: html, css, webiopi

I made a control in HTML to be used in my Raspberry Pi 2 through the framework WebIOPi. When I introduced a type range input, it looks ok in the HTML, but when I ulpload it to my Raspberry Pi and see how it looks, is not good.

[This is how the range input looks in the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPhyf.png)

[And this is how it shows in my local IP address when I upload it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTX7M.png)

As a note, I did not forget to upload the CSS modifications and include it in the header of the HTML file.

I added the input the following way:

```
<input id="volSlider" class="asrange" type="range" min="0" max="30"/>
```

and the CSS:

```
input[type=range] {
width: 10px; /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
height: 100%;
background: transparent; /* Otherwise white in Chrome */
/*transform: rotate(-90deg);*/
-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;

}
```

It appears the same way in Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

Thank you for any answers you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue in your case is the height based on percent. Change that to pixels and follow some additional tips form [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935837/how-to-display-a-range-input-slider-vertically).

```css
input[type=range] {
  width: 10px;
  /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  /* Otherwise white in Chrome */
  /*transform: rotate(-90deg);*/
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  writing-mode: bt-lr;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="volSlider" class="asrange" type="range" min="0" max="30" orient="vertical" />
</div>
```