# Cross-browser vertical input range slider with custom styling

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, slider, webkit

## Slider CSS works in Firefox as desired

[image: firefox-custom-input-range]

## Does not work in Chrome

[image: chrome-custom-input-range]

## Problem elaboration

[Here's a sample](http://codepen.io/KristjanLaane/pen/XMwdVW), which is giving the desired results if viewed with Firefox, but not if viewed with Chrome.

- The key problem is that I seem to need to have this for Chrome: `-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;` - try removing it in the sample and view it in Chrome and the input range becomes horizontal rather than vertical
- But then as a result I cannot hide the native visuals that I have replaced with the custom styling, with `-webkit-appearance: none;`
- I cannot hide them, because it is the same property i.e. `-webkit-appearance` cannot be both `slider-vertical` and `none` in our non-quantum CSS (see under the `[type='range']` selector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29888724/1273587), use transform to make the slider vertical, so you can set `-webkit-appearance` to `none`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the crux

Comment: While there was a need for a lot of changes as the transform messed up the sizing - in the end I had to resort to javascript to position the rotated vertical slider http://codepen.io/KristjanLaane/pen/qmBQqe