# How to customize vertical input range

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was following [this](http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html) tutorial to customize vertical input range, but I don't know how to achieve the same result with vertical input.

I tried to add `transform: rotate(270deg);` rule, but it didn't help.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27jredsp/)

```css
body {
    padding: 30px;
}
input[type=range] {
    /*removes default webkit styles*/
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    
    /*fix for FF unable to apply focus style bug */
    border: 1px solid white;
    
    /*required for proper track sizing in FF*/
    width: 5px;
    
    /* transform: rotate(270deg); */
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 5px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/27jredsp/1/ what is not working ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a range input slider vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15935837/4543207)

Comment: Why dont you use jQuery ui slider https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-range , it is highly customizable

Comment: I changed `input` `width` and `height` and that is the reason why it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is just use the same code from the tutorial, but then add `transform:rotate(90deg);` and `transform-origin: left;` to `input[type=range]` to rotate it vertically.