# Display CakePHP Radio Buttons vertically

Tags: css, cakephp, radio-button, styles, cakephp-1.3

I have this radio button and I want the options to be displayed vertically.

```php
$options = array(
    'LastMonth' => 'Last full month', 
    'Last30' => 'Last 30 days', 
    'LastYear' => 'Last full year', 
    'Last365' => 'Last 365 days', 
    'Custom' => 'Custom'
);
echo $this->Form->input('rank', array(
    'type' => 'radio',
    'legend' => false,
    'options' => $options,
    'selected' => 'LastMonth'
));
```

This is displaying all options in horizontal and i need them to be displayed in vertical. Thanks!!

EDITED: now it displays the options like this.
[image]

HTML:

```html
<div class="vertical-radio-buttons">
    <div class="input radio">
        <input type="hidden" name="data[StatsComponents][rank]" id="StatsComponentsRank_" value="">
        <input type="radio" name="data[StatsComponents][rank]" id="StatsComponentsRankLastMonth" value="LastMonth">
        <label for="StatsComponentsRankLastMonth">Last full month</label>
        <input type="radio" name="data[StatsComponents][rank]" id="StatsComponentsRankLast30" value="Last30">
        <label for="StatsComponentsRankLast30">Last 30 days</label>
        <input type="radio" name="data[StatsComponents][rank]" id="StatsComponentsRankLastYear" value="LastYear">
        <label for="StatsComponentsRankLastYear">Last full year</label>
        <input type="radio" name="data[StatsComponents][rank]" id="StatsComponentsRankLast365" value="Last365">
        <label for="StatsComponentsRankLast365">Last 365 days</label>
        <input type="radio" name="data[StatsComponents][rank]" id="StatsComponentsRankCustom" value="Custom">
        <label for="StatsComponentsRankCustom">Custom</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this thread which is explaining how to display a input of type range vertically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935837/how-to-display-a-range-input-slider-vertically

Comment: I just want to display the options of the radio button in a list in vertical, I don't want a slider :)

Comment: Can you make a snippet of your problem ? It is kind of ambiguous what you are looking for.

Comment: I just want a radio button with 5 posible options, displayed in vertical

Comment: This is primarily a CSS problem, so in order for non-CakePHP people to be able to help you, they would need to see the generated HTML. I guess it would even be helpful for people familiar with CakePHP, personally I can't remember what HTML CakePHP 1.3 generated specifically. Furthermore if you're using a CSS framework of some kind it would be good to mention that, also if you already tried anything to solve the issue.

Comment: If you can post the generated HTML as @ndm says, that would be the key to giving you a solution to your problem.

Comment: For sure. I add the HTML on the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a css problem: putting every `label` and `input` pair inside a `<div>` will solve the problem. In CakePHP 1.3, you can use the `before`, `separator` and `after` options to accomplish this:

```php
echo $this->Form->input('rank', array(
    'type' => 'radio',
    'legend' => false,
    'options' => $options,
    'selected' => 'LastMonth',
    'before' => '<div>',
    'separator' => '</div><div>',
    'after' => '</div>',
));
```