# Why does custom CSS styling not apply due to vertical slider?

Tags: html, css, styling

```css
#slider1 {
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; /* This makes ... */
  background-color: black;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
}

#slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* the difference. */
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
}

#slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb,
#slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04aa6d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover,
#slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="slider1" />
<input type="range" id="slider2" />
```

As seen here, the CSS styling was almost same for both sliders, except for the `-webkit-appearance` property. But the horizontal slider (which is the default slider) accepts the styling while the vertical slider rejects it. I am on Chrome. How to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a range input slider vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935837/how-to-display-a-range-input-slider-vertically)

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I have seen the page before, nothing was mentioned about styling.

Comment: @TonyStark That question doesn't seem to be about vertical slider styling :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is no work around available to design vertical range, what you can do is to rotate the default one.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.slid1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30px;
}

#slider1,
#slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* the difference. */
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
}

#slider1 {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* This makes ... */
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}

#slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb,
#slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04aa6d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover,
#slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="slid1">
    <input type="range" id="slider1" />
  </div>
  <div class="slid2">
    <input type="range" id="slider2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935837/how-to-display-a-range-input-slider-vertically)

Edit: As per your comment, I have wrapped sliders into flex containers to align them.

Comment: Yes, I tried to work with that solution, but as you can see, the code produces a slider shifted to little right. Do you have a solution to fix that? I mean a general solution, not particularly this one.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add custom styling to range slider, you need to set a css property `-webkit-appearance: none;` which you did in **#slider2** but you missed it in **#slider1**.
Try the following code

```
<input type="range" id="slider1" />
<input type="range" id="slider2" />
<style type="text/css">
    #slider1 {
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* This makes ... */
    background-color: black;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100px;
    }
    
    #slider2 {
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* the difference. */
    background-color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1px;
    }
    
    #slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb,
    #slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #04aa6d;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover,
    #slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

Then you will find the vertical slider

Comment: The slider that your code produces doesn't seem to slide smoothly, it only *looks* vertical.

Answer (score 0):

/* can you please try this below CSS code along with your css */

```
/*Chrome*/
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    input[type='range'] {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 80px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;      
    }    
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
      height: 10px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      color: #13bba4;
      margin-top: -1px;
    }
       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#slider1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#slider1, #slider2 {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* the difference. */
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
}

#slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb,
#slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04aa6d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#slider1::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover,
#slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="slider1" />
<input type="range" id="slider2" />
```