# Looking for one RGB color slider picker in React.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am aiming to implement a single slider bar which can control RGB in React.js.
I'm researching react-color etc but
I can't find the ideal one.

The image below is from the mobile app.
It's called ColorSeekBar.
I'm looking for something close.
(This is a bar where you can also choose between Hue and black and white)

[image]

Comment: where is your code that you tried so far?

Comment: No direct solution: If you can't find any, I would recommend to implement it yourself. Also, for beginners this task can offer great learning possibilities as it is an interesting task and will be very satisfying to see working.

- I'd start with using an inverted range input: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15935838/15090924
- CSS to do the background and the slider handle adjustments
- Writing a React component that transforms the input values to colors