# css animation different in browsers

Tags: css, animation, cross-browser

i use firefox as default browser and i never had problem with animations and css in general everything worked fine, but i noticed that in chrome if i have hover effect that has more than one animation, in chrome animations happen in order instead of simultaneously. how can i fix that problem? also the input slider i tried to make it vertical ( works fine in firefox but in chrome it doesn't work at all.

[here is the github pages of the page](https://hawasaki7.github.io/boringlandingpages/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  user-select: none;

}

html,
body,
#root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #bf42f5;
  
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

canvas {
  opacity: 0;
  touch-action: none;
  animation: fade-in 1s ease 0.5s forwards;
}


.nav{
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
 
  min-width: 100%;
}

.nav-list{
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav-list>li{
  padding-right: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.nav-list>li:hover{

  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  scale: 1.11;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  .nav-list{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    /* transform: translateX(1000px); */
  }
  .nav-list>li{
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  .nav-list>li:hover{
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    scale: 1.05;
  }
  
  
}
/*slider*/

.boring-text{
  
  position: fixed;
  left: 5%;
  top: 25%;
}
.boring-text>h1{
  font-size: clamp(2rem, 10vw, 5rem); 
  font-family: 'Sono', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff9a;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-weight: 200;
  max-width: 5ch;
}

.boring-text>h3{
  font-family: 'Marhey', cursive;
  color: #ffffff92;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 5%;
}

.boring-text>h4{
  font-family: 'Sono', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffffba;
}


.slider-wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 10%;
}

.slider {
  writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; /* Chromium */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 5px;
  height: 255px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
/*slider*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marhey:wght@300;400&family=Sono:wght@200;400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>LandingPAGE</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div class='nav'>
    <div class='nav-wrapper'>
        <ul class='nav-list'>
            
            <li>Shop</li>
            <li>Work</li>
            <li>
                apple{/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon="apple" /> */}
            </li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <div class='boring-text'>
      <h1> boring landing pages</h1>
      <h3> phones: {val}</h3>
      <h4> React - Three</h4>
      <div class='slider-wrapper'>
          <input type="range" orient="vertical" min="1" max="50" value='10' class='slider'   />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add a working snippet or piece of code so we can reserch further in your issue. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: sure i will upload snippet asap

Comment: @FrancoGabriel added snippet take a look ))

Comment: I think you're talking about the hover in the navbar, I'm using Chrome and I cannot reproduce this issue, I see all properties taking the same transition time and playing concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the slider you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935837/how-to-display-a-range-input-slider-vertically), it may help you.

About the animations I'm waiting for further information as I reproduce it on your snippet I'm seeing it working well and concurrently.

Comment: to be more specific i get the scale and opacity animation, but padding-bottom doesn't work. after the animation is finished text just jumps up instead of being animated. so i think there is the problem with padding-bottom attribute in hover

Comment: I can recommend you if you're animating the position of an element use `transform: translate( valueX, valueY)` this is going to save you from some re paint issues and is more usual that modifying the padding in an animation.

Comment: thanks again but i had same problem on translate function as well so i need to figure out how transitions work cross-browser and if there are any nuances