# How to style vertically displayed range input so that also works on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile-webkit

I need a vertical range input.
There are two ways to rotate it ([How to display a range input slider vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935837/how-to-display-a-range-input-slider-vertically)):

- -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
- transform

Both do the job in rotating the input itself - but only on desktop. There are two issues though:

1. The transform-rotated version does not work on mobile. You can't drag the thumb, as the whole page will be scrolled instead. The appearance-modified works.
2. But I do need to style it as well (like here: https://codepen.io/zorgoz/pen/KKJoqXX). And that relies on `-webkit-appearance: none;`, which excludes `slider-vertical` to be applied at the same time obviously.

Can I have both?

Answer (score 0):

I started to look from another direction: can I stop the "page drag" instead on that specific element? It turned out that I can. Adding `touch-action: none;` does the job.